# Как скопировать mp3 файл из Интернетов?

Tags: java, mp3, download

Вопрос очень простой. Мой код копирует, но при воспроизведении какие-то прерывания идут. Что я сделал не так?

```
        try {
        URL url = new URL("http://cdn.echo.msk.ru/snd/2017-07-28-osoboe-1908.mp3");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("c:/ww.mp3")));
        int c=0;
        while ((c=br.read())!=-1)
            bw.write(c);
        br.close();
        bw.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e){}
    catch (IOException e){}
    System.out.println("End");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

таким образом проще сделать:

```
URL website = new URL("http://cdn.echo.msk.ru/snd/2017-07-28-osoboe-1908.mp3");
Path target = Paths.get("file.mp3");
try (InputStream in = website.openStream()) {
    Files.copy(in, target, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

Comment: @Hellraiser обновил

Comment: спасибо работает